# Code breaking: Find the solution

Tags: cipher

Try to work out what this means:

> zxmtapznvmntcb

You also have this to work with.

> TTQKVUtXLUM6QQpCRVRBOlM6TAo3Okk6QwoyOlk6TAo1Okg6UQpHRSBYQiBTUSBGSSBLUCBaWSBOVCBXTCBSViBPQyBITQ==

I don't actually know the answer - I just found this and I couldn't work it out.

Comment: Does this come from elsewhere on the internet?

Comment: The solution doesn't exist on the internet, but the code does.

Comment: Where did you find this? Posting puzzles without credit is not permitted here.

Comment: Turns out this was a challenge with actual prizes over at [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjCKovIsEIs), and the answer there was posted only after I solved the puzzle here. Not entirely sure how I feel about that.

Comment: @notHalfBad, please go and clear things up on Youtube; your posting the puzzle here without telling us that there was an ongoing competition involved was not kosher. [Here's the relevant comment thread](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjCKovIsEIs&lc=UgzqXIwDJSLMhpYVCD54AaABAg).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at the time of posting, it was part of an ongoing competition, which an even more egregious abuse of our site policies than simply failing to provide a source.

Answer (score 2):

The message is

> HAPPY HALLOWEEN

First, the tell-tale equals signs at the end suggest that

`TTQKVUtXLUM6QQpCRVRBOlM6TAo3Okk6QwoyOlk6TAo1Okg6UQpHRSBYQiBTUSBGSSBLUCBaWSBOVCBXTCBSViBPQyBITQ==`

is probably a well-formed string in

> base-64 encoding. Sure enough it is. Decoded, it reads
>
> ```
>  M4
>  UKW-C:A
>  BETA:S:L
>  7:I:C
>  2:Y:L
>  5:H:Q
>  GE XB SQ FI KP ZY NT WL RV OC HM
> ```

This looks a lot like

> settings for an Enigma machine. Since I didn't have one handy, I used a [simulator](http://enigma.louisedade.co.uk/enigma.html?m4;c_thin;b725;SIYH;LCME;BX-CO-EG-FI-HM-KP-LW-NT-QS-RV-YZ) to decrypt the message.